# Декодирование кириллицы из json

Tags: c#, json, перекодировка

Вместо кириллических символов получаю `\u4430\u0446`. Библиотеки типа Json.NET не подключаются к моей CRM системе. Так что нужно как-то стандартными декодерами это сделать. Как декодировать стандартными средствами C#?

Вот пример кода:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";
WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);
string str = rdr.ReadToEnd(); 
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: все нормально, это они и есть, читайте [формат](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7), при декодировании должны стать нормальными русскими

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("\u4430\u0446");
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы делаете неправильно. JSON — сериализированный формат, вы должны десериализировать его, и ваши строки будут правильными. То, как выглядят строки в сериализованном виде, не должно быть вам интересно.

Например, вы можете использовать [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{ 'Name': '\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f' }";    
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Name);
```